# How to get the CellID of a cell

Tags: cells

I can count how many cells there are in a notebook up to and including the one whose ID i need, and then evaluate `Cells[EvaluationNotebook[]][[number, 1]]`.

How to do this simpler? And how to get a list of cell IDs when a number of cells are selected?

Comment: `CurrentValue[#, CellID] & /@ SelectedCells[InputNotebook[]]` is this what you want?

Comment: @Kuba Thank you `Dynamic[SelectedCells[EvaluationNotebook[]][[All, 1]], UpdateInterval -> 1]` works. I get ID number 4929, but confusingly `CurrentValue[CellObject[4929], "CellID"]` evaluates to `0`.

Comment: `CellID` option and `CellObject's` id are not the same thing. It would be good to know what do you want at the end.